# PyQt5: Access to QClipboard (or app object) from inside a widget

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, clipboard, pyqt5

I'm trying to access the clipboard (via QClipboard) in a PyQT5 application, but from a widget a few layers deep. The app object usually provides the clipboard via `app.clipboard()` but I don't have access to the app object that deep. Is there a way to access either the clipboard or `app` that doesn't involve passing `app` all the way down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import qApp
```

or:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

qApp = QApplication.instance()
```

The latter is a static method which is inherited from `QtCore.QCoreApplication`. But then again, `clipboard()` also static, so another solution would be:

```
clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
```